# Restriction attribute doesn't work with "0" parameter value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst

In my network dataset I´ve set the restriction attribute - if the value in the field X (integer) is higher than the parameter value (integer), travel on the edge is prohibited. It works well with positive and negative values...but "0" parameter value doesn´t work. It solves the route as if no restriction was there. Do you know why "0" is not a valid value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use -1 or 1. 
The 0-value means that the restriction attribute is disabled or not taken in considering.